# Cant install grpc tools package

Tags: javascript, npm, grpc

when I'm trying to install grpc-tools I get this massive error:
I really don't know what to do

> ```
> npm ERR!   win_delay_load_hook.cc npm ERR!   z.vcxproj -> F:\NodeJS Projects\Noosa\npg\node_modules\grpc\build\Release\\libz.lib
> ```
>
> npm ERR! Failed to execute 'F:\Node js\node.exe C:\Users\Lidor
> German\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js
> build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=F:\NodeJS
> Projects\Noosa\npg\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v93-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node
>
> --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=F:\NodeJS Projects\Noosa\npg\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v93-win32-x64-unknown
> --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1) npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using
> node-pre-gyp@0.14.0 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@16.17.0 |
> win32 | x64 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp
> https download npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "F:\NodeJS
> Projects\Noosa\npg\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v93-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node"
> (not found) npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET
> https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.24.2/node-v93-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
> npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http 404
> https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.24.2/node-v93-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
> npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404):
> https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.24.2/node-v93-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
> npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for
> grpc@1.24.2 and node@16.17.0 (node-v93 ABI, unknown) (falling back to
> source compile with node-gyp)  npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http 404 status
> code downloading tarball
> https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.24.2/node-v93-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
> npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok npm ERR! gyp info using
> node-gyp@9.1.0 npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.17.0 | win32 | x64 npm
> ERR! gyp info ok npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok npm
> ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.1.0 npm ERR! gyp info using
> node@16.17.0 | win32 | x64 npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python
> version 3.10.6 found at "C:\Users\Lidor
> German\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe" npm ERR!
> gyp info find VS using VS2017 (15.9.28307.1500) found at: npm ERR! gyp
> info find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2017\BuildTools" npm ERR! gyp info find VS run with --verbose
> for detailed information npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Users\Lidor
> German\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe npm ERR! gyp
> info spawn args [ npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\Users\Lidor
> German\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\gyp_main.py',
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp', npm ERR! gyp info spawn
> args   '-f', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs', npm ERR! gyp info
> spawn args   '-I', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'F:\NodeJS
> Projects\Noosa\npg\node_modules\grpc\build\config.gypi', npm
> ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args
> 'C:\Users\Lidor
> German\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\addon.gypi',
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args
> 'C:\Users\Lidor
> German\AppData\Local\node-gyp\Cache\16.17.0\include\node\common.gypi',
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library', npm ERR!
> gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default', npm ERR! gyp info spawn
> args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\Users\Lidor
> German\AppData\Local\node-gyp\Cache\16.17.0', npm ERR! gyp info
> spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\Users\Lidor
> German\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp',
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\Users\\Lidor
> German\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\16.17.0\\<(target_arch)\\node.lib',
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=F:\NodeJS
> Projects\Noosa\npg\node_modules\grpc', npm ERR! gyp info spawn
> args   '-Dnode_engine=v8', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel', npm ERR! gyp info
> spawn args   '--generator-output', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args
> 'F:\NodeJS Projects\Noosa\npg\node_modules\grpc\build', npm ERR!
> gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
> npm ERR! gyp info ok npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
> npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.1.0 npm ERR! gyp info using
> node@16.17.0 | win32 | x64 npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe npm ERR! gyp info
> spawn args [ npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build/binding.sln', npm
> ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/clp:Verbosity=minimal', npm ERR! gyp info
> spawn args   '/nologo', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args
> '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64' npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error:
> `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit
> code: 1 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit
> (C:\Users\Lidor
> German\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:201:23)
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
> (node:internal/child_process:291:12) npm ERR! gyp ERR! System
> Windows_NT 10.0.19044 npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "F:\Node
> js\node.exe" "C:\Users\Lidor
> German\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
> "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
> "--module=F:\NodeJS
> Projects\Noosa\npg\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v93-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node"
> "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=F:\NodeJS
> Projects\Noosa\npg\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v93-win32-x64-unknown"
> "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0"
> "--node_napi_label=node-v93" npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd F:\NodeJS
> Projects\Noosa\npg\node_modules\grpc npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v
> v16.17.0 npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.1.0 npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
> npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR!
> stack Error: Failed to execute 'F:\Node js\node.exe C:\Users\Lidor
> German\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js
> build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=F:\NodeJS
> Projects\Noosa\npg\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v93-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node
> --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=F:\NodeJS Projects\Noosa\npg\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v93-win32-x64-unknown
> --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1) npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess. (F:\NodeJS
> Projects\Noosa\npg\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
> npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit
> (node:events:513:28) npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at
> maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1093:16) npm ERR! node-pre-gyp
> ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
> (node:internal/child_process:302:5) npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System
> Windows_NT 10.0.19044 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "F:\Node
> js\node.exe" "F:\NodeJS
> Projects\Noosa\npg\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\bin\node-pre-gyp"
> "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" npm ERR!
> node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd F:\NodeJS Projects\Noosa\npg\node_modules\grpc
> npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v16.17.0 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR!
> node-pre-gyp -v v0.14.0 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok   npm ERR! A
> complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!     C:\Users\Lidor
> German\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-09-05T08_30_41_064Z-debug-0.log

Answer (score 0):

That error is a failure to install the `grpc` package. That package is deprecated, and is not compatible with Node 16. That dependency should be replaced with `@grpc/grpc-js`.